# Oracle Apex - Email with custom link

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form where users can create tickets, these tickets are managed by a Team Leader who at the same time assigns each of the tickets to members on his/her Team.
I know how to send out emails via Process or Dynamic Action but! I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on how to send a custom link. For example:

''A new ticket #12345 has been assigned to your queue, please follow this link to review:
(link)''

I want that specific link to go directly into ticket #12345 in the App.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the page in question has a page-level item for the ticket you want to display.  If so, you'd just need to generate a URL that includes that parameter using [`apex_page.get_url`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/GET_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI30190) (or the older `apex_util.prepare_url` if you're on an older version)

```
apex_page.get_url( p_application => :APP_ID,
                   p_page        => x,
                   p_items       => 'Px_TICKET_ID',
                   p_values      => '12345' )
```

would return the URL assuming that `x` is the page that displays information about a single ticket and that that page allows you to pass a value for the ticket ID you want to display using the `Px_TICKET_ID` page item.

Comment: thanks! will try this approach now

Comment: This is probably generating a session ID into the URL, and you probably do not want to send a session ID by mail.

Answer (score 1):

Only to complement the last answer[image: query example]

```
SELECT APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (
        p_page   => 1,
        p_items  => 'P1_X,P1_Y',
        p_values => 'somevalue,othervalue' ) f_url_1,
     APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL('f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.::::P1_X,P1_Y:somevalue,othervalue')
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: gracias! ayuda bastante